# View glitch when navigating from PreferenceFragmentCompat fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-navigation

I have this weird bug that I can't figure out.
I have 3 fragments and use Android Navigation to navigate between them. Everything works perfect, but as soon as I go to settings fragment that has access to preferences and navigate back to main fragment which has list view, one TextView in ListAdapter item has this highlight happen for a few seconds and then it's gone. From now on whenever I navigate from any fragment back to this one, the highlight happens, until I restart the app.

Any ideas?

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkeWB.png)

Comment: Please add you layout file for the list view items. Also, in what manner does the highlight disappear? Fade out? They all disappear instantly, at the same time?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mak1nt0sh/bf5d658803922b43b2684ed5063026fa The highlight disappears by fading out, all at the same time. Also if I change the number and title textview the highlight appears on the title then. Check out my answer below, I found out how to fix it. However it would be interesting to hear your opinion on what is causing it..

Comment: Hmm, dunno. It'd almost have to be your choice of `textAppearance`. Not sure what you mean by "change the number". Can't help but think it's actually a transparency, and the "highlight" is actually you looking through to the item shadow, or to the old fragment.

Comment: I meant changing the text views doesn't matter. The highlight still appears on the bottom view. Removing textAppearance does nothing. It's really strange that this is somehow related to preference library.

Comment: I would try adding like 20dp of margin to your TextView, and see what happens. Or maybe padding. (Maybe if the artifact is bigger, it will be easier to see what it is).

Comment: Nor margin, nor padding changes anything. The highlight just sticks to the last letter of the text. If I put empty string [""] there, it is gone tho. If I put [" "] it comes back again. Also It seems that it only reproduces when I go back from Fragment that extends PreferenceFragmentCompat()

Comment: Then make the font bigger :)

Comment: Ok.. I solved it by changing MaterialCardView layout height to wrap content.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution.

Changed MaterialCardView or top layout height to wrap_content.

Or

Downgrading Preference library to 1.1.0-aplha01 solves it too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added fragment or replace that in container? it is issue when you add multiple fragments and before adding new it's not removed. so please use replace fragment and also check with addToBackStack() method.

Comment: How do I replace fragment when navigating from settings fragment? The only way to go back is to use upnavigation button. Also I clear the backstack when navigating from other fragments back to main one with popBackStack however the issue is still there.