# After switching from the PreferenceFragmentCompat fragment

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, fragment, preferencefragmentcompat

After switching from the PreferenceFragmentCompat fragment to the regular fragment. TextView ([TextView vertical line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXifr.jpg)) element and EditText ([EditText vertical line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdyYN.jpg)) input element have a black horizontal line, which disappears after 5 seconds. How to remove the appearance of a vertical line?

Comment: I think this is what you want to achieve. A custom editText, please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189265/custom-designing-edittext

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59357573/view-glitch-when-navigating-from-preferencefragmentcompat-fragment